# JSF PROJECT_STAGE Production and f:param

Tags: java, jsf

I have recently changed my JSF version from 2.2 to 2.3, which modified the default value of `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` from `Development` to `Production`. This resulted in unexpected behaviour - the value of `f:param` is no longer included in the `ExternalContext requestParameterMap`.

Use case is simple - I wish to perform validation only when specific user action occurs. For example:

```
<h:commandLink value="Save changes">
    <f:param name="performValidation" value="true"/>
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.save()}"
            execute="#{cc.clientId}:content"
            render="#{cc.clientId}:content" 
            onevent="showLoader"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

This executes some inputs including a hidden one with attached validator:

```
<h:inputText style="display:none;" value="abc" validator="#{bean.validate}"/>
```

The validator code looks like this:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (!"true".equals(context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("performValidation"))) {
        return;
    }

    ... Prepare the List<FacesMessage> and throw it in ValidatorException if not empty ...
}
```

Messages are displayed in single `h:messages` component placed inside the rendered container with `rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}"`.

Setting `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` in `web.xml` to `Development` resolves the issue. Still, I would love to understand - why the `Production` setting is breaking this code?

---

**EDIT:**

I am using `Mojarra: 2.3.5.SP2`. Below you can see the POM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.asdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>asdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Omnifaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.10.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it Mojarra or MyFaces? Which exact version? How does `pom.xml` dependencies element look like?

Comment: @Selaron I have included the requested information.

Comment: [mcve] please so it is easier for others to try to reproduce if they feel like it.